# jQuery-like selectors for PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, jquery, css, xml, css-selectors

I'm working with a [`DOMDocument`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), and I'm wondering if there exists some way of using CSS-like selectors to select nodes like we would in [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Example situation: I'm parsing an XML file, one snippet of which looks like this:

```
<gesmes:Envelope>
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time="2009-07-13">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.3975"/>
            <Cube currency="JPY" rate="129.03"/>
            <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
            <Cube currency="CZK" rate="26.028"/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

Accessing this structure with jQuery-like selectors would be dead simple. For example, I could use

```
$("Cube[currency]")
```

to retrieve all the `Cube` elements with the 'currency' attribute.

But how can I do the same thing with PHP's `DOMDocument`? I'd like to select elements which have an attribute, or have a particular attribute value.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to manipulate the DOM ala Jquery, PHPQuery is something for you.

http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

A simple example of what you can do with it.

```
// almost everything can be a chain
$li = null;
$doc['ul > li']
        ->addClass('my-new-class')
        ->filter(':last')
                ->addClass('last-li');
```

Comment: WOW, amazing! My only doubt is the future reability... what if the project will stop? Using DomDocument will be more safe i suppose.. but i'òll give it a try!

Comment: It uses DOMDocument backwards, so you should not be worry about that ;) in the end, it is just a wrapper that provide syntactic sugar for all your DOM needs...

Comment: Yes, i've seen that is really 'just' an API to the php DOM's API ;)
But it works like magic, even with large files.
Thanks man!

Comment: -1; phpQuery sucks and after suffering horribly from its defects I recommend against ever using it. It's abandonware (last commit February 2010) with [over 100 open bugs](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/issues/list?can=2&q=type%3DDefect&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&num=100&start=0), including really basic stuff like errors from [typoed variable names](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/issues/detail?id=231). Stay far away from this; find another library or learn to [use Xpath via the built-in DOM library](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

Comment: Im a big phpquery fan, its awesome to be able to use the same css3 queries id use in javascript. I've never had an issue with phpquery other than the same character encoding issues id have with native DOMDocument, also it looks like there was a commit a year ago. Their documentation does kinda SUCK though

Answer (score 19):

Take a look at the [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) class in PHP. It uses XPath, so you'll need to read up on XPath syntax if you're unfamiliar with it. There's some documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx), or you can read the [W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) if you're particularly brave.

To solve your example problem: `//cube[@currency]` is an XPath query that selects all elements in the document with a currency attribute. Usage of this with the `DOMXPath` class would look like this:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($myDomDocument);
$cubesWithCurrencies = $xpath->query('//cube[@currency]');
```

`$cubesWithCurrencies` is now a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) that you can iterate over.

Answer (score 8):

I created a library that allows you to crawl HTML5 and XML documents just like you do with jQuery.

You can find the library [**on GitHub**](https://github.com/PHPPowertools/DOM-Query).

It should allow you to do exactly what you want!

Under the hood, it uses [**symfony/DomCrawler**](https://github.com/symfony/DomCrawler) for conversion of CSS selectors to XPath selectors. It always uses the same DomDocument, even when passing one object to another, to ensure decent performance.

The library also includes its own zero config autoloader for PSR-0 compatible libraries. The example included should work out of the box without any additional configuration.

---

Example use:

```
namespace PowerTools;

// Get file content
$htmlcode = file_get_contents( 'https://github.com' );

// Define your DOMCrawler based on file string
$H = new DOM_Query( $htmlcode );

// Define your DOMCrawler based on an existing DOM_Query instance
$H = new DOM_Query( $H->select('body') );

// Passing a string (CSS selector)
$s = $H->select( 'div.foo' );

// Passing an element object (DOM Element)
$s = $H->select( $documentBody );

// Passing a DOM Query object
$s = $H->select( $H->select('p + p') );

// Select the body tag
$body = $H->select('body');

// Combine different classes as one selector to get all site blocks
$siteblocks = $body->select('.site-header, .masthead, .site-body, .site-footer');

// Nest your methods just like you would with jQuery
$siteblocks->select('button')->add('span')->addClass('icon icon-printer');

// Use a lambda function to set the text of all site blocks
$siteblocks->text(function( $i, $val) {
    return $i . " - " . $val->attr('class');
});

// Append the following HTML to all site blocks
$siteblocks->append('<div class="site-center"></div>');

// Use a descendant selector to select the site's footer
$sitefooter = $body->select('.site-footer > .site-center');

// Set some attributes for the site's footer
$sitefooter->attr(array('id' => 'aweeesome', 'data-val' => 'see'));

// Use a lambda function to set the attributes of all site blocks
$siteblocks->attr('data-val', function( $i, $val) {
    return $i . " - " . $val->attr('class') . " - photo by Kelly Clark";
});

// Select the parent of the site's footer
$sitefooterparent = $sitefooter->parent();

// Remove the class of all i-tags within the site's footer's parent
$sitefooterparent->select('i')->removeAttr('class');

// Wrap the site's footer within two nex selectors
$sitefooter->wrap('<section><div class="footer-wrapper"></div></section>');

[...]
```

---

Supported methods :

- [x] [$](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) *(1)*
- [x] [$.parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/)
- [x] [$.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)
- [x] [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)
- [x] [$selection.add](http://api.jquery.com/add/)
- [x] [$selection.addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)
- [x] [$selection.after](http://api.jquery.com/after/)
- [x] [$selection.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
- [x] [$selection.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [x] [$selection.before](http://api.jquery.com/before/)
- [x] [$selection.children](http://api.jquery.com/children/)
- [x] [$selection.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [x] [$selection.contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)
- [x] [$selection.detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)
- [x] [$selection.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
- [x] [$selection.eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)
- [x] [$selection.empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) *(2)*
- [x] [$selection.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [x] [$selection.first](http://api.jquery.com/first/)
- [x] [$selection.get](http://api.jquery.com/get/)
- [x] [$selection.insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)
- [x] [$selection.insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)
- [x] [$selection.last](http://api.jquery.com/last/)
- [x] [$selection.parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [x] [$selection.parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)
- [x] [$selection.remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)
- [x] [$selection.removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)
- [x] [$selection.removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)
- [x] [$selection.text](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [x] [$selection.wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

---

1. *Renamed 'select', for obvious reasons*
2. *Renamed 'void', since 'empty' is a reserved word in PHP*

Comment: @LucasBustamante : Normally, you should be able to just download the repo & run the sample in the "examples" folder without any additional config. Does this work for you? If not, what happens instead? If yes, how are you trying to use the library?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Symfony DomCrawler component, enabling you to use css selectors for DOM traversing:
https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/dom-crawler

Comment: Install the CssSelector component too and use filter() !

Answer (score -2):

XPath is exactly what you are looking for, [here is pretty good list of possible selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: Though XPath is suitable for selecting by element name, it is horrible for selecting by attribute value (class, id, etc.). Furthermore, it chokes on invalid XML and most HTML on the web is not valid XML.

Comment: Actually you can load incorrect HTML with DOMDocument::loadHTML() and query it with XPath.