# PHP: Explode CSS selectors and compare with a list

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

I got an Object of [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net), which I can use to gather some information.

**To get the tag of an element I can use:**

`$element->parent()->tag();`

The result is a string like `span` or `div`.

**To get the attributes I am using**

`$element->parent()->getAllAttributes();`

*A possible result is*

`["id"]=> string(4) "huhu" ["class"]=> string(5) "heyho"`

or just

`["id"]=> string(4) "huhu"`

On the other side I got an array with elements like those:

```
array(11) { [0]=> string(2) "em" [1]=> string(5) "style" [2]=> string(1) "a" [3]=> string(3) "img" [4]=> string(4) "code" [5]=> string(3) "pre" [6]=> string(15) "span.helloworld" [7]=> string(2) "h1" [8]=> string(2) "h2" [9]=> string(2) "h3" [10]=> string(6) "button" } array(11) { [0]=> string(2) "em" [1]=> string(5) "style" [2]=> string(1) "a" [3]=> string(3) "img" [4]=> string(4) "code" [5]=> string(3) "pre" [6]=> string(15) "span.helloworld" [7]=> string(2) "h1" [8]=> string(2) "h2" [9]=> string(2) "h3" [10]=> string(6) "button" } array(11) { [0]=> string(2) "em" [1]=> string(5) "style" [2]=> string(1) "a" [3]=> string(3) "img" [4]=> string(4) "code" [5]=> string(3) "pre" [6]=> string(15) "span.helloworld" [7]=> string(2) "h1" [8]=> string(2) "h2" [9]=> string(2) "h3" [10]=> string(6) "button" } array(11) { [0]=> string(2) "em" [1]=> string(5) "style" [2]=> string(1) "a" [3]=> string(3) "img" [4]=> string(4) "code" [5]=> string(3) "pre" [6]=> string(15) "span.helloworld" [7]=> string(2) "h1" [8]=> string(2) "h2" [9]=> string(2) "h3" [10]=> string(6) "button" } array(11) { [0]=> string(2) "em" [1]=> string(5) "style" [2]=> string(1) "a" [3]=> string(3) "img" [4]=> string(4) "code" [5]=> string(3) "pre" [6]=> string(15) "span.helloworld" [7]=> string(2) "h1" [8]=> string(2) "h2" [9]=> string(2) "h3" [10]=> string(6) "button" } array(11) { [0]=> string(2) "em" [1]=> string(5) "style" [2]=> string(1) "a" [3]=> string(3) "img" [4]=> string(4) "code" [5]=> string(3) "pre" [6]=> string(15) "span.helloworld" [7]=> string(2) "h1" [8]=> string(2) "h2" [9]=> string(2) "h3" [10]=> string(6) "button" } array(11) { [0]=> string(2) "em" [1]=> string(5) "style" [2]=> string(1) "a" [3]=> string(3) "img" [4]=> string(4) "code" [5]=> string(3) "pre" [6]=> string(15) "span.helloworld" [7]=> string(2) "h1" [8]=> string(2) "h2" [9]=> string(2) "h3" [10]=> string(6) "button" } array(11) { [0]=> string(2) "em" [1]=> string(5) "style" [2]=> string(1) "a" [3]=> string(3) "img" [4]=> string(4) "code" [5]=> string(3) "pre" [6]=> string(15) "span.helloworld" [7]=> string(2) "h1" [8]=> string(2) "h2" [9]=> string(2) "h3" [10]=> string(6) "button" } array(11) { [0]=> string(2) "em" [1]=> string(5) "style" [2]=> string(1) "a" [3]=> string(3) "img" [4]=> string(4) "code" [5]=> string(3) "pre" [6]=> string(15) "span.helloworld" [7]=> string(2) "h1" [8]=> string(2) "h2" [9]=> string(2) "h3" [10]=> string(6) "button" }
```

Now I would like to do something, only if the tag (and, if given, the attributes) are matching.

The first thing is easy:

```
if ( in_array( $element->parent()->tag, $excludedParents ) { ... }
```

The second thing is a problem, because I would have to split up `span.helloworld` and compare the `tag` and the `attributes`.

Next thing is: It should be possible with other css-like selectors, too (just like `span#id`).

### To give you a full example:

**The html-content looks like this:**

```
<article class="uk-article uk-text-center">
    <p><span class="helloworld">Lorem ipsum dolor</span> sit amet <span id="huhu" class="heyho">consectetur
</article>
```

**Now I am looping through all text elements:**

```
    foreach ( $dom->find( 'text' ) as $element ) {      
        if ( !in_array( $element->parent()->tag, $excluded ) ) {    
                $element->innertext = "test";
        }
    }

    return $dom->save();
```

Alright. Let's have a look at the `$excluded`:

`dump($excluded);`:

```
array:12 [▼
  0 => "em"
  1 => "style"
  2 => "a"
  3 => "img"
  4 => "code"
  5 => "pre"
  6 => "h1"
  7 => "h2"
  8 => "h3"
  9 => "button"
  10 => "ul"
  11 => "span.helloworld"
]
```

Now unfortunately the test `if ( !in_array( $element->parent()->tag, $excluded ) )` does only work on real tags. But not on "jQuery-like" selectors like `span.helloworld`.

The problem is: The class/id/other attributes are saved this way:

`dump($element->parent()->getAllAttributes());`:

```
array:1 [▼
  "class" => "uk-article uk-text-center"
]
```

or

```
array:1 [▼
  "class" => "helloworld"
]
```

or

```
array:2 [▼
  "id" => "huhu"
  "class" => "heyho"
]
```

This tells me, that I would have to "split up" the selector and check if it is a class-selector, an id-selector, ... .

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: That's hard to follow. Why not give a sample of html and expected results?

Comment: Of course. I added a full example. I know it's a bit abstract, but I hope it's getting more clear now.

Comment: Would it not perhaps make more sense if you used a library that supports CSS selectors to begin with …? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124271/jquery-like-selectors-for-php-domdocument

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you  mean. You would have to go up 2 and check if the children match the css. Something like:

```
foreach ( $dom->find( 'text' ) as $element ) {      
  foreach($excluded as $css){
    foreach($element->parent->parent->find("> $css") as $parent){ // check children of gp
      if($parent == $element->parent) continue(3);
    }
  }
  if ( !in_array( $element->parent()->tag, $excluded ) ) {    
    $element->innertext = "test";
  }
}
```

unfortunately I don't think the simple-html-dom child selector (`>`) is reliable so you might have some problems.